# how to change a number formatted cell in google sheets and set it to a string

Tags: google-apps-script

> I tried to add a '0' to the beginning of each NUMBER cell, this code did convert the number to a string , but when I set theValue() of the cell to this string it was automatically converted back to a NUMBER removing the 0 at the beginning

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()

 function editNums() {
  var selected;
  var selectedValue;

  for(i =0; i < lastRow; i++){
   selected = sheet.getRange(i+1,6);
   selectedValue = selected.getValue();
   
   if(typeof selectedValue === 'number'){
     var combinedNum = '0' + selectedValueString;

     Logger.log(typeof(combinedNum))

     selected.setValue(combinedNum)

     Logger.log(selected.getValue())
   }
  }
 }
}

editNums()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this is how you format a cell or cells:
> will use your example.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
```

> example cell selection

```
selected = sheet.getRnge(4, 3)
```

> get the cell value

```
var selectedValueString = selected.getValue()
```

> the new wanted value

```
var combined = '00' + selectedValueString;
```

> this will format the cell to a string(text)

```
    selected.setNumberFormat("@")
```

> now set the value with a string

```
    selected.setValue(combined)
```